# Number of Cards Until 5 Kings Flipped Over Game

Tags: probability, game-theory

"The dealer is known to deal cards from a deck that is comprised of 10 standard card decks. This means that there are 40 of each rank of card and 520 total cards. The dealer plays a game where he shuffles all 10 decks together randomly, and then he starts turning over cards from the top of the deck. Once he turns over 5 kings, the game is over. You win the game if you are closest to how many cards total (including the final king) the dealer turns over before the game ends. How many cards would you guess to maximize your chances?"

My solution is as follows: it is equally likely for a King to appear anywhere in the deck as well as any other card, so we can use a symmetry argument. There are 480 cards that aren't a King, meaning that there are in expectation 480/41 cards in between Kings. Therefore, the answer is 480/41*5 + 5 (to add in the extra 5 kings) ~ 63.5, so we choose 63. The answer is 53, and they do not use symmetry. Why is my answer incorrect?

The answer description is attached in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBkbd.png).

Comment: It seems the discrepancy is occurring in what the optimal strategy is to maximize your chances. The solution claims that the optimal strategy is to pick the number of cards drawn that has the highest probability of occurring. You claim that the optimal strategy is to pick the expected value of the number of cards drawn.

Comment: But also, I will say the game seems a bit vague. When it says you win if you are the closest, what are we comparing your guess with?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Probably the correct question is about the maximizing the chances to correctly guess the number of cards by the end of the game. Though even a guess is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: The maximum of the probability (which you are probably asked about - see my previous comment) is not the same thing as the expected value.

Comment: I see, so we have to actually create the PDF and maximize it to find the maximal probability – that makes sense, but it's a bit weird that the expected value is not the optimal strategy. Why is that? Even if the probability is the highest that isn't a correlation to the most probable number of cards showing up (LOTUS)

Comment: The main problem of your question is that the sentence "You win the game if you *are closest to* how many cards total (including the final king) the dealer turns over before the game ends. " makes no sense (see the comments above). One obviously should replace "are closest to" with "correctly guess".